# LRU is used in file system cache?

Tags: caching, file-io, lru

I learned that due to computational overhead, true LRU is not implemented in virtual memory systems.  So, why is the LRU algorithm feasible in a file cache?

I think reason is may be the time field in an inode.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

It's about speed.

Virtual Memory status bits must be updated in nanoseconds, so hardware support is needed, and status information for LRU is expensive to implement in hardware.  E.g. the clock algorithm is designed to approximate LRU with less expensive hardware support.

File system operations are on the order of milliseconds.  A CPU can do LRU in software in a very small fraction of this time. Milliseconds are so "slow" from the CPU's point of view (190-thousands of instructions) that preventing only a small number of cache misses produces a big payoff.

Comment: @우지식 You're welcome.  If the answer was helpful it would be good if you accepted it.